# XMLHttpRequest returns response before page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to automate the search function at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/#search/ using XMLHttpRequest, but the response is coming back before the results have loaded.

If you put a search term like Layer, Geoprocessor, Legend, etc. on the end of the url above and load the page, the #sample-thumbs div will contain links to samples that contain the search term. It takes about 10 seconds to load though, and the request returns before that, so the #sample-thumbs div is not yet present and the #samplesLoading div is still visible.

Here is my request function; I am checking that readyState is 4 and status is 200 before returning the response, so XMLHttpRequest thinks the page is fully loaded. The page is mostly complete, apart from the results div, which takes a further few seconds to load.

```
function doAjaxRequest (requestUrl, callback) {
    var ajaxRequest;

    // Create a request Object
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                callback(ajaxRequest.response);
            }
        }
    };
    // Set response type
    ajaxRequest.responseType = "document";
    // Open url
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
    // Send request
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

So, the question is, can I make XMLHttpRequest wait until #sample-thumbs has appeared? Or can I make a second request (or multiple requests) to the same page to check if this div has appeared yet? It seems like the XMLHttpResponse is just returning a snapshot, so should I be using another method to get a dynamic response, which will continue to update as the page loads?

Sorry, that's actually three questions. Basically I'm asking if what I'm trying to do is possible with XMLHttpRequest, and if not, what else could I use?

UPDATE:
Here's a full snippet. If you set a breakpoint at line 25 (.innerHTML += ...) and watch ajaxRequest.responseXML.querySelectorAll("#samplesLoading"), you can see the loading div is there. The #sample-thumbs div is not.

```js
function doAjaxRequest(requestUrl) {
  var ajaxRequest, loadingDiv;

  // Create a request Object
  ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if (ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += ajaxRequest.response.querySelectorAll("#sample-thumbs ul");
      }
    }
  };
  // Set response type
  ajaxRequest.responseType = "document";
  // Open url
  ajaxRequest.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
  // Send request
  ajaxRequest.send(null);
};

function doSearch() {
  var requestUrl;

  // build query url
  requestUrl = "https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/#search/";
  doAjaxRequest(requestUrl + document.getElementById("searchTerm1").value);
};
```

```html
<div id="bcMain">
  <div id="cpRequest">
    <h2>Request test</h2>
    <label for="searchTerm1">Search Term 1</label>
    <input id="searchTerm1" type="text"/>
    <br><br>
    <button id="btnHttpRequest" type="button" onclick="doSearch()">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div id="cpResults">
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a working (failing :-) snippet?

Comment: @Amit - here you go. Enter the search term in the check box and click the button. Querying #sample-thumbs returns an empty NodeList.

Comment: do your ajax on document.ready event and then you are sure html is fully loaded

Comment: "is just returning a snapshot, so should I be using another method to get a dynamic response, which will continue to update as the page loads" *wat?*

Comment: this `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += ajaxRequest.response.querySelectorAll("#sample-thumbs ul");` is doing exactly what it's supposed. It's just not what you want it to do

Comment: @meskobalazs I'm talking live collection vs static collection https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#A_.22live.22_collection. Response is static, right?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, the problem is that we arrive at this line while the samples are still loading. ajaxRequest.readyState is 4 even though the page is not yet complete.

Comment: @jon_two A HTTP response has nothing to with DOM. HTTP is stateless, so the question makes no sense, really.

Comment: @jon_two - those samples can't load before you get the HTML, but that's not the problem either. The code you have there doesn't do what you think it does at all

Answer (score 1):

If you make an XMLHttpRequest before the page has loaded, of course it can happen that it will return before the page has loaded.

The solution is really simple, wait until the DOM is ready, *then* make your request. The `ajaxRequest.readyState == 4` is only checking if the AJAX request is ready, it makes no claims about your DOM tree.

If you need constantly updated data in your web application, then AJAX in itself is not enough. Traditionally this was solved with Comet-like solutions, long polling etc. But fortunately, lately you can use WebSockets, which makes bidirectional communication possible in a web application.

Comment: Did you even look at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/#search/? When you go to the page, the search starts. I don't see how I can wait for the page to load before making my request. Making the request triggers the page load. It's all one process.

Comment: making the request does not trigger the page to load. making the request returns a bunch of HTML. It's not until that HTML (or the part you want) is in the DOM that the images you want could possible begin to load. The problem is, those images are loaded by javascript, so, you'd also have to load the javascript. Your whole concept is fundamentally flawed

Comment: could not have said it any better

Comment: @JaromandaX _"making the request does not trigger the page to load"_ ok, so that explains why I'm getting a page without any results. _"you'd also have to load the javascript"_ any idea how I could do this? _"Your whole concept is fundamentally flawed"_ I'm new to Javascript, so don't understand a lot of this. That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: If I'm getting this correctly, you're basically, instead of using the ArcGIS API, you want to abuse their site, and you're stuck in that.

Comment: I understand you don't know what to do, if I had an answer I'd post it, but as the concept is flawed it's too much work to even work out what you'd need to do

Comment: What I want to do is do two searches then find the samples that are common to both. For example, to find a sample that uses Legend and Geoprocessor. I can do this manually, but it's a bit tedious and I was hoping it could be automated. What I attempted here clearly is not the answer.